# Code Assist for Javascript Canvas object

Tags: javascript, eclipse-indigo, aptana3, code-assist

I'm stuck (after hours of trying to get unstuck). Main problem is that I would like to have class-specific code assist for javascript objects I retrieve from the DOM. For example,
if I retrieve a  element using document.getElementById("theCanvas"), I only get code assist for a generic DOM object (which is logical). I would like to be able to "tell" the javascript editor that this object is actually a Canvas, so that I could then get code assist for the Canvas object.

I've installed Aptana and JSEclipse. With Aptana, I can't even find an Aptana (or Django) editor to associate with .js files. In the JSEclipse documentation (what of it there is), it mentions that you can enable this with JSDoc, but I have been unable to make this work. Also, JSEclipse doesn't seem to support formatting, which seems really odd.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get code assist for this case and/or how to access the Aptana js editor and/or how to get JSEclipse to format? I was thinking maybe you could cast the element object (a la Java), but the only documentation I could find on this says you can only do 3 casts in Javascript (Number, Boolean and String).

Platform: Eclipse Indigo for Java EE Developers (including WTP), Aptana 3.0.8, jdk 1.6.25, JSEclipse 1.5.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Javascript isn`t strongly-typed and not compilated, this way is more difficult to IDEs to understand what are you meaning while you are writing.

But fortunately, you can use the Console of Google Chrome to help you with that. It knows the attributes and methods of the objects you are using

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how that helps. I mean, if I'm in the Chrome console, I'm not editing. I'd like the support while I'm writing the code.

Comment: well, you will not be able to auto-increment the code in your IDE but if you don`t know exactly the attributes, methods or types of an object the Chrome console is helpful